# Why is my alert not displaying on page load, but it will display if I do it immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("HI");
)};
```

Alert never shows up though. But if I remove the document.ready part, it will load immediately. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure you're loading jQuery? Post *all* of the relevant code.

Comment: Take a look in the console for errors.

Comment: Have you opened up your browser's developer tools to check for errors?

Comment: I don't see why it's saying this: http://i.imgur.com/g5WRbS4.png

Comment: Ugh, I just had the parantheses in the wrong place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typographical error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a typo. The last line should be `});` not `)};`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Variables starting with `$` signify (generally since other libraries could use `$` sign too) jQuery objects. So its most likely your jQuery object is not loaded.

When you remove the `$(document).ready ..)` it becomes just plain javascript and you get the `alert("hi")`.

**ALSO** there is this typo in the last line `)};`  should be `});` which only means your jQuery variable of `$(document)` was not set properly.

Answer (score 2):

The last line should be

```
 })
```

instead of

```
 )}
```